# Symfony как поменять домен?

Tags: symfony

Нужно ли где прописывать домен?
Или же тот адрес который в сервере он отвечает за домен и просто смены в домена для корневой директории будет достаточно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будет достаточно. В настройках symfony домен не прописывается